# Str object has no attribute "add"

Tags: python

Can someone help me fix this:

```
import random
import operator
from operator import add, sub, mul
from random import randint

score = 0

name = input("What is your name? ")

for i in range(10):
    n1 = randint(1,10)
    n2 = randint(1,10)
    ops =[["+", operator.add],["-", operator.sub],["*", operator.mul]]

    randomOp = random.choice(list(ops))

    operator = randomOp[0]
    op = randomOp[1]

    prod = op(int(n1), int(n2))

    ask = ("What is",int(n1),operator,int(n2),"?")

    ans = input(ask)
    if ans == ("%d" % (prod)):
        print ("That's right -- well done")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print ("No, The answer is %d. " % (prod))

print (name, "I asked you 10 questions. You got %d of them right." % (score))
print ("Quiz is finished")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: In this case, I was able to *guess* quite quickly as to how you got your error, but had you posted the full traceback we wouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assigned a string to the `operator` name:

```
operator = randomOp[0]
```

You are now masking the `operator` module. Don't re-use names like that, because the next iteration of your `for` loop `operator.add` now tries to look up the `add` attribute on that string (so one of `'+'`, `'-'` or `'*'`, whatever the first iteration picked by random choice).

You also imported the 3 functions directly:

```
import operator
from operator import add, sub, mul
```

so a simple solution would be to use those 3 names instead of referencing the functions on the module:

```
ops = (("+", add), ("-", sub), ("*", mul))
```

where I used tuples instead of lists (since altering the `ops` sequence in your code would probably be an error). You could move that assignment *out* of your `for` loop as well; there is little point in recreating it each iteration.